# gitflow init, what happens inside, after to execute

Tags: git

I've tested gitflow init, on the shell with a existing project:

```
$ git flow init -f

Which branch should be used for bringing forth production releases?
   - develop
   - master
Branch name for production releases: [master] 

Which branch should be used for integration of the "next release"?
   - develop
Branch name for "next release" development: [develop] 

How to name your supporting branch prefixes?
Feature branches? [feature/] 
Release branches? [release/] 
Hotfix branches? [hotfix/] 
Support branches? [support/] 
Version tag prefix? []
```

and with gitkraken.

After the question to name the branches,( i left all in default values)
i can use gitflow commands, but what happened inside ? i don't see new files on the project folder. what gitflow did, to init.  the gitflow init create files ? where?
I downloaded a git project teorically using gitflow, but i need anyway use gitflow. how gitflow realiza a project is initiated ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`gi flow init` "just" modifies the git configuration of the repository. So you can see these values in the file `.git/config`.

The configuration of a repository is NOT checked in and hence can NOT be transported between repositories. Every user/committer/contributor has to initialize `git flow` on their local repositories.